# Inherited entity property sometimes is null

Tags: java, glassfish, eclipselink, ejb-3.1

I have a very strange situation that is only intermittently reproducible in one particular developer's environment and I'm looking for thoughts on where to look for the cause.

In this case there's an entity which is a subclass of an abstract base class. The model uses a JOINED strategy. For example,

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "Foo.findNextForProcessing", query = "SELECT f FROM Foo f WHERE f.status IN (some statuses) ORDER BY f.priority DESC, f.id ASC")})
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable, Comparable {

  @Id
  @Generated Value(generator="fooSeq", strategy=GeneratorType.SEQUENCE)
  @SequenceGenerator(name="fooSeq", sequenceName="SEQ_FOO_ID", allocationSize=1)
  private long id;

  @Version
  private int version;

  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private int priority;

  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(nullable = false)
  @Index
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private FooStatus status;

  @Index
  private String foo;

  //Getters and Setters, ctor, toString, compareTo
}

@Entity
public class Bar extends Foo {

  //No @Version property - uses base class for that

  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String pathName;

  //Getters & Setters, toString - no ctor
}
```

Bar is created in a method that is an EJB 3.1 SSB whose injected PersistenceContext is a JTA resource (backed by Glassfish 3.1.2 (Eclipselink 2.3.2v20111125-r10461) JDBC Resource/Connection pool to an Oracle 10g Express 10.2.0.1.0 server using the ojdbc6 thin driver).

The code is logging the details of Bar when it is created and its confirmed that indeed Bar has its fields along w/its parents) filled in.

Concurrent to these being created a @Singleton bean has a method annotated with @Asynchronous and @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED) which polls for Foo objects with a particular FooStatus.

The EJB polling method is something like this:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "APP1")
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Resource
SessionContext sctx;

@EJB
FooBean fooBean;

@Asynchronous
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void run() {
  while(!shouldStop) {
    try {
      sctx.getBusinessObject(Poller.class).innerPoll();
    }catch(EJBException ejbex) {
     ...
    }catch(Exception ex) {
     ...
    }
  }
}
```

The innerPoll() method is where Foo's are fetched by calling a method on fooBean which was injected into the Poller class. It looks like this:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void innerPoll() throws PollerException {
...
  List<Foo> results = fooBean.fetchNextForProcessing(int maxResultSize);
  for (Foo foo : results) {
    if (foo instanceof Bar) {
      log.debug("priority: " + foo.priority); //Always has a value for priority!
      log.debug("pathName: " +((Bar)foo).pathName); //Prints "pathName: NULL" sometimes! - 
    }
  }
...
}
```

The query that does the fetching in fooBean looks like this:

```
TypedQuery<Foo> q = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Foo.findNextForProcessing", Foo.class);
q.setFirstResult(0);
q.setMaxResult(maxResultSize);
return q.getResultList();
```

The named query looks something like this:

```
SELECT f FROM Foo f WHERE f.status IN (some statuses) ORDER BY f.priority DESC, f.id ASC
```

It takes the result list (List) of this polling and checks to see which subclass (Bar etc. - there are actually a few other subclasses of Foo besides Bar) they are instances of.

In the case of an instance of Bar if we call ((Bar)afoo).toString() we observe (only on this one devs machine - and only sometimes!) that the properties associated with Bar (pathName, name, etc.) are NULL and the properties associated with its base class (foo, status etc.) are filled in correctly.

If we force an exception to occur after printing out a Bar and confirming aBar.pathName is NULL so that the the while loop in run() will catch the exception and re-execute the innerPoll() call we see that aBar will have its properties filled in on that (and all) subsequent fetches.

It feels like a timing issue but whats odd is that Bar is created atomically in its own TX which sets its and its inherited properties so I am not sure how when the polling thread picks it up the base class properties are filled in but the subclass properties are still NULL. This broken behavior only happens sometimes and only happens on this one particular machine.

Could this have something to do with the Eclipselink level 1 cache and version change tracking? The persistence.xml has the following parameter set:

```
eclipselink.cache.shared.default=false
eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing=Oracle-JDBC
eclipselink.order-updates=true
eclipselink.jdbc.native-sql=true
```

So nothing related to weaving or version tracking is changed from its defaults.

Comment: This does feel like a timing issue. Are you sure that the EJB transaction where you are committing the db changes is actually committed?

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE] - In the Glassfish JDBC Connection Pool settings, unchecking the "Non Transactional Connections" setting of the connection pool used by the JTA resource seems to have fixed the issue and does explain why he was the only one affected as he was the only one with this setting checked off but I'm still not clear if this is a bug or intended behavior.